# Distribution for Sum of Square Normal Variables with Arbitrary Variance

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

Let $X_1\sim N(0,\sigma_1^2), X_2\sim N(0,\sigma_2^2),\dots,X_n\sim N(0,\sigma_n^2)$ where generally $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2\neq\sigma_3\dots\neq\sigma_n$. What is the distribution of the statistic
$$Y = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2}?$$

The distribution for $Y^2$ is obtained by a combination of [Distribution of sum of squares of normals that have mean zero but not variance one?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186775/distribution-of-sum-of-squares-of-normals-that-have-mean-zero-but-not-variance-o) and [General sum of Gamma distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/general-sum-of-gamma-distributions), but I don't know enough about characteristic functions to see if there's any easy way of incorporating the square root.

Comment: The [chi distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution) is probably what you want.

Comment: It would be a good idea to clarify whether you want the $X_i$ to be independent: I can't see that in your question at the moment.

Comment: By the way, on this site there's no need to say "thank you" at the end of your post - it 
might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site 
([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" and it means future 
readers of your question don't need to read through the pleasantries.

Comment: Yes, I do mean independent. The chi distribution seems good if all of the distributions are standard normal, but does it still work in this more general case?

Sorry....I try to be polite in my first posts, before I know a place.

Comment: Greenparker was absolutely right for my first typing of the formula, in which I absent mindedly divided each of the $X_i$ by its standard deviation. The currently typed version is the actual statistic I am interested in.

Comment: Another way of thinking about this question is, "what is the distribution of the Euclidean norm of a zero centered multivariate normal with diagonal covariance".

Comment: Yes, Indeed this is the application which it has come from.

Comment: The distribution of $Y^2$ is found at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479 (because the $X_i^2$ have Gamma distributions). The form of the answer suggests you won't find a nice closed analytical solution. The saddlepoint approximation suggested in the answer by kjetil b halvorsen might be appealing.

Comment: Are the variances n=known or unknown?