# How do gamma distributions add and what would that model?

Tags: distributions, modeling, gamma-distribution, convolution

Density distributions add by convolution, and the result is also a density distribution. So writing this in the time domain, w.l.o.g., the question becomes how do we take a faster gamma distribution:

${\mathrm{GD_{fast}}}\left(\mathrm{a} ;\ \mathrm{b}; \tau \right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\hfill \frac{{\mathrm{b}}^{\mathrm{a}}}{\Gamma \left(\mathrm{a}\right)}{\tau}^{\mathrm{a}-1}{e}^{-\mathrm{b}\kern0.1em \tau },\hfill & \hfill \tau\ \ge\ 0\hfill \\ {}\hfill \kern2.75em 0\kern1.5em ,\hfill & \hfill \tau <0\hfill \end{array}\right.,$

where $\tau $ is time, and add it to a slower one:

${\mathrm{GD}}_{\mathrm{slow}}\left(\alpha; \beta; \tau \right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\hfill \frac{\beta^{\kern0.1em \alpha }}{\Gamma \left(\alpha \right)}{\tau}^{\alpha -1}{e}^{-\beta\;\tau },\hfill & \hfill \tau \ge 0\hfill \\ {}\hfill \kern3em 0\kern1.2em ,\hfill & \hfill \kern1.4em \tau <0\hfill \end{array}\right.,$

The notation here assigns the rate scalar $\beta=\frac{1}{\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the time scalar. Both parameterizations are in [common use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). Thus, when we require $b>\beta$, we are requiring that $\text{GD(b)}$ to be faster (e.g., lighter right-tailed) than $\text{GD}(\beta)$. The solution is well known for the simpler case when $\mathrm{b}=\beta$; it is also a gamma distribution. But what we (**Q1**) want is a  general closed form convolution solution for the sum of two gamma distributions: a gamma distribution convolution of the type

$\mathrm{GDC}\left(\mathrm{a}\kern0.1em ,\mathrm{b},\alpha, \beta; \tau \right)={\mathrm{GD_{fast}}}\left(\mathrm{a},\mathrm{b};\;\tau \right)\otimes {\mathrm{GD_{slow}}}\left(\alpha, \beta; \tau \right),$

Finally, we (**Q2**) want some indication of whether this can be used to form reasonable models, and whether or not it has found practical applications.

Comment: @Glen_b I looked, and it was not, not in closed form. As a recursion, yes, and approximate answers, yes. And, it was whuber who answered it, and his comment is below the answer and his comment below the answer refers to this post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/general-sum-of-gamma-distributions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A procedural solution for $n$ tuple convolution is given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72486/99274).

**Q1:** The two gamma distribution  convolution (GDC) in closed form is only given here

$\mathrm{G}\mathrm{D}\mathrm{C}\left(\mathrm{a}\kern0.1em ,\mathrm{b}\kern0.1em ,\alpha, \beta; \tau \right)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\hfill \frac{{\mathrm{b}}^{\mathrm{a}}{\beta}^{\alpha }}{\Gamma \left(\mathrm{a}+\alpha \right)}{e}^{-\mathrm{b}\tau }{\tau^{\mathrm{a}+\alpha-1}}{}_1F_1\left[\alpha, \mathrm{a}+\alpha, \left(\mathrm{b}-\beta \right)\tau \right],\hfill & \hfill  \tau >0\hfill \\ {}\hfill \kern2em 0\kern6.6em ,\hfill  \kern5.4em \tau \kern0.30em \le \kern0.30em 0\hfill \end{array}\right.,$

which is a density function consisting of a gamma variate multiplied by $_1 F _1(A; B; Z)$, where the latter is a [confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), and see end note below. For $\text{b} = β$, this equation reduces to the well known result 
$$\text{iff b}=\beta\text{;}\;{\mathrm{GD}}\left(\mathrm{a},\mathrm{b};\;\tau \right)\otimes {\mathrm{GD}}\left(\alpha, \text{b}; \tau \right)=\text{GD}(\text{a}+α,\text{b} ;τ)$$

An even more general solution with weights is given in Eq. (2) [here](http://old.sis-statistica.org/files/pdf/atti/Spontanee%202006_511-514.pdf). Furthermore, that reference lists a non-closed form solution for the sum of $n$ weighted gamma distributions.

**Q2:** No applications for the GDC have been posted on CV prior to this. Most recently, the GDC has been used in medicine for the first time to model [radioactive tracer activity in time in the thyroid gland](http://ejnmmiphys.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40658-016-0166-z). GDC models have also [been applied](http://old.sis-statistica.org/files/pdf/atti/Spontanee%202006_511-514.pdf) for ecological water storage I/O, waiting times in queuing theory, and in the evaluation of aggregate economic risk of portfolios.

End note: The fast computation of the confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind uses the [Euler's integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations) identity ${}_1F_1\left(A;B;Z\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(B\right)}{\Gamma \left(B-A\right)\Gamma \left(\mathrm{A}\right)}{\displaystyle {\int}_0^1{\mathrm{e}}^{Z\;u}{u}^{A-1}{\left(1-u\right)}^{B-A-1}du}$.

Comment: +1.  There is a typo in the final formula: "$t$" should be "$u$" in [Euler's integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations).  Note, too, that we have a thread which generalizes this result to [finite sums of arbitrary Gamma distributions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479).

Comment: @whuber Typo noted and corrected.