# sum of two gamma distributions with different scales using change of variable

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Let $X_1\sim\Gamma(r,1)$ and $X_2\sim\Gamma(s,1)$ be independent. Find the distribution $Y=X_1+X_2.$

Comment: Those appear to be different shapes not scales

Comment: And if they were different scales there isn't a closed-form solution

Comment: Complementing what Thomas Lumley said, for different scales the resulting distribution is not "elementary", but it can be described in terms of a hypergometric function, according to this post  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/252192/238955

Answer (score 3):

The distribution functions for $X_1$ and $X_2$ we write out as
\begin{align*}
f_1(x_1)&=\frac{x_1^{r-1}e^{-x_1}}{\Gamma(r)}\\
f_2(x_2)&=\frac{x_2^{s-1}e^{-x_2}}{\Gamma(s)},
\end{align*}
with moment-generating functions
\begin{align*}
m_{X_1}(t)&=(1-t)^{-r}\\
m_{X_2}(t)&=(1-t)^{-s}.
\end{align*}
Now it is a theorem that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables, then $X_1+X_2$ has a moment-generating function equal to the product of the moment-generating functions for $X_1$ and $X_2.$ That is, for our case,
$$m_{X_1+X_2}(t)=m_{X_1}(t)\,m_{X_2}(t)=(1-t)^{-r}(1-t)^{-s}=(1-t)^{-(r+s)},$$
which is the moment-generating function for a Gamma distribution with parameters $r+s$ and $1.$ That is, $X_1+X_2\sim\Gamma(r+s,1).$ This last step follows because moment-generating functions are unique.

Comment: This should be treated as a `self-study` question. Providing the (correct and well-detailed) solution does not necessarily help the OP in the long run.

Comment: Though the solution doesn't use change of variables, as the OP wanted...

Comment: Yes, the fact that I didn't use the intended method sort of satisfies that self-study issue. At least they have the correct answer.