# Distribution of sum of $n$ random variables with mixture of two exponential distributions

Tags: distributions, mixture-distribution, exponential-family, sum, finite-mixture-model

Suppose that the random variable $Y$ follows a mixture of two exponential distributions, that is

\begin{equation}
f_Y(y) = \sum_{i=1}^{2}\pi_i f(y| \lambda_i)
\end{equation}
where $\pi$ stands for mixing weights with the property that $\sum_{i=1}^{2}\pi_i = 1$, and that $f(y|\lambda_i) = \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i y}$, for $i=1, 2$. Let $\{Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_n\}$ be a random sample from the above-mentioned mixture distribution. Now consider the new random variable $Z$, which is defined to be
\begin{equation}
Z= \sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_j
\end{equation}
Is it possible to find the density function of $Z$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This derivation is directly feasible by considering the latent variable representation of a mixture random variable. Each of the $Y_i$ is associated with a latent Bernoulli variable $\xi_i\sim\mathfrak B(\pi_2)$ in the sense that
$$Y_i|\xi_i=k\sim\mathfrak Exp(\lambda_{k+1})\qquad k=0,1$$
Therefore, $$Z=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$$ can be conditioned upon the vector of latent variables$$\boldsymbol\xi=(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)$$and written as
$$
Z|\boldsymbol\xi
\sim\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\big|\boldsymbol\xi
\sim\Big(\underbrace{\sum_{i;\,\xi_i=0} Y_i}_{\substack{\text{sum of iid}\\ \mathfrak Exp(\lambda_1)}}+\underbrace{\sum_{i;\,\xi_i=1} Y_i}_{\substack{\text{sum of iid}\\ \mathfrak Exp(\lambda_2)}}\Big)\Big|\boldsymbol\xi
$$
This means that, conditional on$$\zeta=\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i\sim\mathfrak B(n,\pi_2)$$$Z$ is distributed as the sum of a Gamma $\mathfrak G(n-\zeta,\lambda_1)$ and of a Gamma $\mathfrak G(\zeta,\lambda_2)$, i.e.,
$$
Z|\zeta\sim Z_1+Z_2\qquad Z_1\sim \mathfrak G(n-\zeta,\lambda_1),\ \ 
Z_2\sim\mathfrak G(\zeta,\lambda_2)\tag{1}
$$
The distribution of this sum (1) is itself a *signed* mixture of Gamma distributions with at most $n$ terms and rates either $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$, as shown in the earlier [X validated post of @whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72486/7224).¹ Integrating out $\zeta$ (or marginalising in $Z$) leads to a mixture of $n+1$ terms, the weight of the $k$-th term is the Binomial probability$${n\choose k}\pi_2^k\pi_1^{n-k}$$
In conclusion, the distribution of $Z$ can be represented as a signed mixture of Gamma distributions with an order $O(n^2)$ terms.

A more direct approach is to consider the $n$-fold convolution representation of the density of $Z$:

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} f_Y(y_i)
f_Y(z-y_1-\cdots-y_{n-1})\,\text dy_1\cdots\,\text dy_{n-1}$$

and to expand the product of the $n$ sums $f_Y(y_i)=\pi_1 \mathfrak e(y_i|\lambda_1)+\pi_2 \mathfrak e(y_i|\lambda_2)$ into $2^n$ terms, which when regrouping identical convolution integrals again results into a sum of $n+1$ terms,

$$f_Z(z) =\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}\pi_1^k\pi_2^{n-k}\int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^k \mathfrak e(y_i|\lambda_1)}_{\substack{\text{leading to}\\ \mathfrak G(k,\lambda_1)}}\,\underbrace{\prod_{i=k+1}^n
\mathfrak e(y_i|\lambda_2)}_{\substack{\text{leading to}\\ \mathfrak G(n-k,\lambda_2)}}\,\text dy_1\cdots\,\text dy_{n-1}$$

where $y_n=z-y_1-\cdots-y_{n-1}$.

> The most compact representation for the density is thus
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\pi_2^k
>   \pi_1^{n-k}\dfrac{\lambda_1^{n-k}\lambda_2^{k}}{\Gamma(n)}e^{-\lambda_1z} z^{n-1}\; _1F_1(k, n, (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)z)$$

---

¹Or equivalently a distribution with a more complex density involving a confluent hypergeometric function $_1F_1$ as shown in the [earlier CV post of @Carl](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/252192/7224).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I should go through your answer as it is not easy foe me to fully understand why, for example, $Z$ conditional on $\zeta$ is distributed as the sum of two gamma distributions. BTW, if we have this conditional distribution, it is still possible to find the distribution of $Z$? I think you have derived the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $\zeta$.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask why you first consider $Z|\xi$ and then work with $Z|\zeta$?

Comment: can we proceed further with the last formula you wrote in order to derive a closed-form expression?

Comment: Ok, I see. So, the final result is represented by a signed mixture of Gamma distributions, can I ask how this kind of distribution looks like. You said that I can refer to X validated post of @whube. It seems that a solution based on the confluent hypergeometric function exists. Is this called a signed mixture of Gamma distributions?

Comment: But I think this kind of representation is applicable when we have gamma distributions with the same $\lambda$. BTW, I want to write down the distribution function of $Z$ to compute a quantity that is based on it.

Comment: So, this is what we will have, according to your explanation:
\begin{equation}
f_Z(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} f(z, \zeta) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}f(z|\zeta) f(\zeta =k) \\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\pi_2^k \pi_1^{n-k}\frac{\lambda_1^{n-k}\lambda_2^{k}}{\Gamma(n)}e^{-\lambda_1z} z^{n-1}\; 1F_1(k, n, (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)z)
\end{equation}

Comment: sorry, we can say that the above representation is a signed mixture of gamma, right?

Comment: Computationally, it is doable to calculate the $F_Z(y)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq y)$ according to the above representation?

Comment: I greatly appreciate your time and help.

Comment: I have a question. At the beginning of your proof, you have considered latent variable $\xi_i$ to be the Bernoulli variable with parameter $\pi_2$, which is interpreted as the probability of success. Since we usually write $Y\sim \pi \textbf{EXP}(\lambda_1) + (1-\pi)\textbf{EXP}(\lambda_2)$, maybe it is better to write $\xi_i \sim \mathcal{B}(\pi_1)$.