# Probability generating function of mixture of discrete random variables

Tags: probability-generating-fn

> Consider a discrete distribution $X$ that is a *mixture* of two
>   discrete distributions $A$ and $B$. Explicitly, $X=A$ with probability
>   $p$ and $X=B$ with probability $1-p$. Denote the pgfs of $A$ and $B$
>   as $\mathcal{G}_A$ and $\mathcal{G}_B$ respectively.

I want to write an expression for the pgf $\mathcal{G}_X$ of $X$.
Here's what I've done so far, am I on the right track?

Let $Y\sim X$ and denote the probability measure on $A$ and $B$ as $\mathbb{P}_A$ and $\mathbb{P}_B$ respectively. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y=k) &= \begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}_A(Y=k) & \textrm{with probability $p$} \\
\mathbb{P}_B(Y=k) & \textrm{with probability $1-p$}
\end{cases} \\
&= p\mathbb{P}_A(Y=k) + (1-p)\mathbb{P}_B(Y=k)
\end{align*}
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{G}_X(z) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k\mathbb{P}(Y=k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k\left(p\mathbb{P}_A(Y=k) + (1-p)\mathbb{P}_B(Y=k)\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}pz^k\mathbb{P}_A(Y=k) + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-p)z^k\mathbb{P}_B(Y=k) \\
&= p\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k\mathbb{P}_A(Y=k) + (1-p)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k\mathbb{P}_B(Y=k) \\
&= p\mathcal{G}_A(z)+(1-p)\mathcal{G}_B(z)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Pay attention to title. In probability theory, there are several kinds of generating function, so need to specify which you want to talk.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution and the general method are both correct, but some of your notation is unnecessary (e.g., there is no need to define $Y$ at all).  Note that this result is just a special case of a more general probability rule, which holds that that the probability generating function of any mixture random variable can be written as a weighted average of the probability generating functions of its mixture parts (with weights equal to the mixture probabilities).

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be a mixture of the random variables $A_1,...,A_k$ with mixture probabilities $p_1,...,p_k$, then the [probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) of $X$ 
>   can be written as:$$\mathcal{G}_{X}(z) = \sum_{i=1}^k p_i \cdot \mathcal{G}_{A_i}(z).$$
>
> **Proof:** From the stated mixture form we have $X = A_H$ where $H \sim \text{Categorical}(p_1,...,p_k)$.  Thus, using the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) you have:$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
> \mathcal{G}_{X}(z) 
> = \mathbb{E}(z^X) 
> &= \mathbb{E}(z^{A_H}) \\[6pt]
> &= \mathbb{E}( \mathbb{E}(z^{A_H}|H)) \\[6pt]
> &= \mathbb{E}( \mathcal{G}_{A_H}(z)) \\[6pt]
> &= \sum_{i=1}^k p_i \cdot \mathcal{G}_{A_i}(z), \\[6pt]
> \end{aligned} \end{equation}$$ which was to be shown.  $\blacksquare$

Observe that nothing in this proof requires any assumption about the distributions of the random variables $A_1,...,A_k$ to be discrete.

Comment: +1 -- but by deleting the unnecessary word "convex" everywhere you will make the underlying idea even clearer and provide an interesting generalization.

Comment: @whuber: Edited.

Comment: Thank you.  Note that the $p_i$ needn't be probabilities: there are applications where distributions are expressed as linear combinations of others with negative coefficients (or even complex coefficients).  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72486/919 for an example.

Comment: @whuber: Fair enough, but would you still call that a "mixture distribution"?

Comment: I understand why one might want to restrict the coefficients to positive numbers, but have yet to run into a situation where that restriction was necessary or useful.  In some sense, allowing for negative coefficients is akin to introducing imaginary numbers in algebra: they might not admit the same interpretations as ordinary numbers, but they can be useful and ultimately might provide more satisfactory explanations of otherwise mysterious behaviors.