# what is the simplified expression for the sum of probability of exponential distributed data?

Tags: probability, gamma-distribution

[image]

Hi, I want to find the expression of P(Y1+...+Yn>U) as shown in the screeshot below but I have no idea how to do this. I'm not sure whether I should use Erlang distribution or gamma distribution. Please advise. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: let say Y_i is the monthly expenses, and U is an unknown threshold, so what should be the probability of n month expenses exceed the threshold?

Comment: Please add `self-study` tag and tell us why using [the distribution of the sum of the $Y_i$'s](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/72479/7224) is not helping.