# Euclidean Norm normalized Normal Distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, euclidean, truncated-normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a multivariate normal $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma^2)$ and let $X$ be anistropic, that is I am considering $\Sigma$ to be a diagonal matrix but the elements on the diagonal might be different.

I am interested in finding the distribution of $X/\|X\|_2$.

As a start for $X$ isotropic. Then $\|X\|_2^2$ will be Gamma Distributed. But then $\|X\|_2$ will perhaps have to follow what I found to be a Nakagami Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution). So I need to find a ratio of a normal and this Nakagami distribution. However for the anisotropic case $\|X\|_2^2$ will not be gamma but a mixture of Gamma distributions ([Generic sum of Gamma random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/generic-sum-of-gamma-random-variables)) and this seems more complicated to be honest.

On the other hand it feels intuitively to be somewhat similar to a truncated normal distribution but with the truncation happening over a unit ball and this also seems complicated.

Comment: It's not a truncated distribution.  Its shape will depend on the relative values of *all* the diagonal elements: there's no general simplification.  Thus, it's not worth mathematical analysis: in a statistical setting one would seek approximations or use numerical methods.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why is not worth the analysis. I agree it depends upon the diagonal values. But why is such an analysis not possible

Comment: Also could you expand on approximations

Comment: Such an analysis is possible, but the result is necessarily messy because it will depend on every one of the parameters--the $\mu$ and the $\Sigma^2$ components.  How insightful or useful would that be?  I use "approximation" in its standard sense: formulas that are much simpler and will do the intended job, albeit with some error (that we would hope to provide bounds for).

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question I answered on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398261/norm-contrained-gaussian-distribution/398272#398272