# Why my cdf of the convolution of n exponential distribution is not in the range(0,1)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution, convolution

I assume that there are n exponential distribution that $x_i$ ~ $Exp(\lambda_i)$, i=1..n, and I want to calculate the cumulative distribution of $S=x_1+x_2+...+x_n$, the convolution of n exponential distribution. I used the formulation that I read in a paper given by,
$$1-\sum_{i=1}^n (\prod \limits_{j=1,j\neq i}^n \frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i})e^{-\lambda_i t}$$
but when I set $\lambda_i = 0.01i+2$, and $n=20$, then when t=0, the result is not equal to 0.

Comment: This site is not the place for debugging computer code--especially not nearly illegible and uncommented code of unspecified type. If you have a statistical question, please ask it. Maybe start by seeing if your equation works for the convolution of two exponential distributions, and ask about that.

Comment: Actually I think there is no bug on me code, I just want to show the result calculated.

Comment: As it says: "If the question is actually a statistical topic disguised as a coding question, then OP should edit the question to clarify this. After the statistical content has been clarified, the question is eligible for reopening."

Comment: This is a partial fractions expansion, as described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/72486/919.  It does not hold generally (for instance, it is constantly equal to $1$ when $n=1,$ which is incorrect; and it is undefined if any pair of the $\lambda_i$ are equal). When it does apply *theoretically*, the calculation is numerically unstable for small $t$ because it involves a great deal of near-cancellation of large terms.  Thus, *this formula is unsuitable for general calculation.* You need a different algorithm.  One attractive possibility is to invert the characteristic function.

Comment: BTW, because questions about algorithms for computing quantities of statistical interest are on topic here, I have voted to reopen this thread.  (+1)

Comment: @Sextus Here is a compact `R` implementation of the formula.  `f <- Vectorize(function(t, lambda) {
  1 - sum(apply(outer(lambda, lambda, function(x,y) ifelse(x==y, 1, y * exp(-x * t)/(y-x))), 1, prod))
}, "t")`. As an example of its use (in a case where it works!) see `curve(f(x, seq_len(6) * 1e-2 + 2), 0, 3, lwd=2)`  Changing `6` to `20` gives the case in the question and clearly reveals the problem.  There is a clash of conventions between this formula and your convention for $\lambda,$ btw.

Comment: @Sextus Yes, it's a lot different because your $\lambda$ appears to be the *reciprocal* of the $\lambda$ in the formula.  I say "appears" because the formula in this question clearly isn't quite correct.  For instance, it reduces to a constant $1$ when $n=1.$  I just don't feel like checking it ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Method 1: Order distribution

You can alternatively model this as an order distribution. There is a [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283180/466748) between sums of exponentials and order distributions of exponentials.

Since you are looking for the special case of $\lambda_i = 0.01i+2$ and $n=20$ this link works. The sum is similar to the sampling of $m = 220$ exponential distributions with $\lambda = 0.01$ and taking the 20-th smallest sample.

Then we can model the CDF as a beta distribution transformed by the exponential quantile function.

So if $X \sim Beta(20,220+1-20)$ then $Y = -100 \cdot \ln(1-X)$ is distributed as the sum of $20$ exponential distributed variables with $\lambda_i = 0.01i+2$

#### Method 2: Hypoexponential distribution

More generally, the sum of exponentials is [hypoexponential distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution). The CDF of the hypoexponential distribution can be expressed in terms of a matrix exponential and this can be used to compute it. The matrix exponential is defined as the Taylor series but with $X$ a matrix: $e^{X} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}X^k$. Several fast algorithms exist to compute it (besides using the first terms in the Taylor series).

#### Code demonstrtion

The code below demonstrates these methods:

[image: comparison]

```r
set.seed(1)
library(Rmpfr)
library(matrixcalc) ### allows us to use matrix.power

###
### theoretic computation based on beta distribution
###
k = 20
xs = seq(0,k*2,0.1)        # values x to compute CDF for
pe = pexp(xs,0.01)         # cdf of exponential
pb = pbeta(pe,k,200+k+1-k) # cdf of beta based on p from cdf of cdf of exponential

###
### theoretic computations 2 sum of exponential functions
### with a trick with logarithms to improve computations
###
h = function(t, precision = 53) {
  
  ### using variables with different precision
  l = mpfr(seq(2.01,2+0.01*k,0.01), precision)
  p = mpfr(rep(1,k),precision)
  
  ### computing the product and sum
  for (j in 1:k) {
    for (i in 1:k) {
      if (j != i) {
        p[j] = p[j] * l[i]/(l[i]-l[j])
      }
    }
  }
  
  ### return the result
  as.double(1-sum(p*exp(-l*t)))
}
h = Vectorize(h)

###
### theoretic computation using hypoexponential distribution
###
g = function(t) {
  ### generate matrix for hypo-exponential distribution
  l = seq(2.01,2+0.01*k,0.01)
  M = diag(-l)
  diag(M[-k,-1]) = l[-k]
  
  ### compute CDF using matrix exponential
  1-sum(expm(t*M)[1,])
}
g = Vectorize(g)

###
### simulation of summing 20 exponential distributed variables 
###
sim = function() {
  l = seq(2.01,2+0.01*k,0.01)
  sum(rexp(k,l))
}
n = 10^3
y = replicate(n, sim())
y = y[order(y)]
ps = c(1:n)/n
  
###
### plot results
###

layout(matrix(1:4,1))

plot(y,ps, type = "l", ylim = c(0,1),
     xlab = "y", ylab = "p(X<=x)", col = 1, lty = 1,
     main = "estimate using \n beta distribution")
lines(xs, pb, col = 2, lty = 2)

plot(y,ps, type = "l", ylim = c(0,1),
     xlab = "y", ylab = "p(X<=x)", col = 1, lty = 1,
     main = "estimate using \n hypo exponential distribution")
lines(xs, g(xs), col = 2, lty = 2)

plot(y,ps, type = "l", ylim = c(0,1),
     xlab = "y", ylab = "p(X<=x)", col = 1, lty = 1,
     main = "estimate using \n sum of exponential functions")
lines(xs, h(xs), col = 2, lty = 2)

plot(y,ps, type = "l", ylim = c(0,1),
     xlab = "y", ylab = "p(X<=x)", col = 1, lty = 1,
     main = "estimate using \n sum of exponential functions \n high precision")
lines(xs, h(xs, precision = 106), col = 2, lty = 2)
```

#### Method 3: Higher precision

The code above has your formula included as well. When $n = 20$ and we compute $P(X\leq 0)$ then we get the sum of numbers in the order around $10^{30}$:

```r
> p*exp(-l*t)
20 'mpfr' numbers of precision  200   bits 
 [1]  1184377704791549923796136956.607426574485340044851136466504687
 [2] -22391774527715875503095258875.03263232345792580141668597954522
 [3]  200533231977287736716622162734.3838677372979407569824559548119
 [4] -1130784613649661547175898714626.269008683529273781772412307854
 [5]  4501074364576350873051048293822.423602640254497752902071819979
 [6] -13437673467060135092418439694475.71911050588558126590977544721
 [7]  31203100063608817375763652531058.33729082993747843780866417281
 [8] -57670015296133360609431486185964.71343501537022605441586568593
 [9]  86091123312888841776163054615053.45436911041487039497542827845
[10] -104721424601233110811921244247537.9049963527831300886304307068
[11]   104225114532032942398284597644451.965294335372683402639022954
[12]  -84872852699970611190163244498094.3346219654358556203530876458
[13]  56316259068524588993874802018151.08761670825436672186290382369
[14] -30182437911995447023357731135651.16278839986713601836568813731
[15]  12875166205648313573257565589226.63372958778154884796895991358
[16] -4271852984898851750101954219568.873097418541709901194303528335
[17]  1063041756610741552892528679905.931481962365234315486381160982
[18] -186735073813712898818348384333.2996752734412911578062357660226
[19]  20653600249308703228634568900.71910148094711050404923349682836
[20] -1082090539377734264859901133.234415028798941489661772836725247
> sum(p*exp(-l*t))
1 'mpfr' number of precision  200   bits 
[1] 1.000000000000000000000000000065346803013058912494189331591907
>
```

So that answers your question 'why you do not get results in the range between 0 and 1'. It is because the computation depends on adding several very large positive and negative numbers which need to cancel each other (Whuber already mentioned this in the comments).

By using quadruple floating-point numbers we can compute it more accurately (but it is not a very fast computation).

Comment: Many thanks for your help!