# Distribution of half-life from radioactive decay

Tags: distributions, poisson-process

Suppose that $X$ measures the half-life of a radioactive element, with decay rate $\lambda$ (per unit of time).

Starting from a population of $N$ particle, I believe you can model the number of particles that decay over a unit of time as a $Poisson(N\lambda)$, and that the time until the first decay is detected is modeled using an $Exponential(N\lambda)$.

*My question is*: How can we model the distribution of the half-life $X$, i.e., starting from a population of $N$ particles, the amount of time it takes for $N/2$ of the particles to have decayed ?

Assuming the decays are independent from one another, it seems an Erlang distribution could be appropriate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution? Should I then use $f(x,N/2,N\lambda)$ (where the notation refers to the Wikipedia article)? If the half-life intuition is correct, it would seem $f(x,N/2,N\lambda)$ should then be invariant to the choice of $N$, but that's not obvious to me looking at the algebraic for of the Erlang's pdf. Is that correct? If so, there should be a single distribution $g = f(x,N/2,N\lambda)$ for all $N$ that models half-lifes?

Comment: I am not sure you are correct that the number of particles that decay over a unit of time has a Poisson distribution, partly because a Poisson distribution has unbounded support but you cannot have more than all the particles decay.

Comment: @Henry: Good point. In practice, for this kind of application, $N$ is typically very large (number of particles in a batch of matter) and $\lambda$ relatively small. So I am hoping it would still provide a good approximation? Independence issues aside, to be more precise, I guess I could use a $Bi(N, \lambda)$?

Comment: If $N$ is large and $\lambda$ is small then it will be a long time until half of the particles have decayed.  Initially you will be seeing about $N \lambda$ decays per unit time and close to a Poisson process.  The issue is that until this rate of decays starts to slow down noticeably, you will have no good way of estimating the overall half-life of about $\frac{\log_e(2)}{\lambda}$, and once it does slow down it will no longer be a homogeneous Poisson process.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder, then, how physicists have managed to measure the half-lives of long-lived isotopes like $U^{238}$  (half life, $4.5\times 10^9$ years) with such accuracy.  Answer: any macroscopic mass contains a huge number of particles so even over a short period of time a very large number of decays occur, providing precise estimation of $\lambda.$ @Henry

Comment: @whuber $N\lambda$ is easy to measure reasonably accurately if you have enough decays: just count the number of decays in a second or a day or whatever.  The question is separating $N$ from  $\lambda$ since you are interested in $\lambda$.  For long-lived isotopes, you create a pure sample with a known total mass and a known atomic mass, dividing one by the other and multiplying by Avogadro's number then gives you $N$.

Comment: *"Assuming the decays are independent from one another, it seems an Erlang distribution could be appropriate"* The Erlang distribution is for a sum of exponential distributed variables with the *same* rate. In your case the rate will change as the number of particles is not constant. So you get a sum of exponential variables with *different* rates. This can be computed as explained here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/566651/164061 or as in whuber's answer.

Answer (score 13):

**You ask about the distribution of an *order statistic*** $X_{(k)}$ of $N$ independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N$ and $k=N/2$ when $N$ is even and $k=(N+1)/2$ when $N$ is odd.  Because this order statistic is *the* median when $N$ is odd and otherwise is *a* median, I will refer to it henceforth as the "median."

When the common distribution function $F$ has a density $F^\prime = f,$ the order statistic has a density, too, given by

$$f_{k;X}(x) = \binom{N}{k-1;1;N-k}\, F^{k-1}(x) f(x) (1-F(x))^{N-k}.$$

**By choosing time units in which the half-life is $1$,** the exponential distribution function is $F(x) = 1 - e^{-x},$ whence $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and therefore

$$f_{k;X}(x) = \frac{N!}{(k-1)!(N-k)!} e^{-(N-k+1)x}\left(1 - e^{-x}\right)^{k-1}.$$

One way to understand this is to express it in terms of $U = e^{-X}$ (which, incidentally, has a Uniform$[0,1]$ distribution).  The density of $U$ is

$$f_{k;U}(u) \ \propto\ u^{N-k}(1-u)^{k-1},$$

immediately recognizable as that of a Beta$(N+1-k, k)$ distribution.  Thus, $X_{(k)}$ is seen as the (negative) logarithm of a Beta variable.

**Here, for example**, are histograms of the median of $N=12$ Exponential variables (from 40,000 simulations) and its negative exponential on which, in red, graphs of $f_{k;X}$ and $f_{k;U}$ have been overlaid to demonstrate the correctness of this analysis.

[image: Figure]

**At this point you can apply what is known about the Beta distribution** to determine in great detail anything you like about the distribution of $X_{(k)},$ so I won't belabor the point.  Instead, consult the references, including the following CV threads:

- For more about the distributions of medians generally, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160148/919.
- For a detailed analysis of how such distributions approach a Normal distribution as $N$ increases, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86804/919.  Use this for accurate approximations when $N \gg 10$ or so.
- See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/225990/919 for a sketch of how the initial formula for $f_k$ can be derived.