# Probability of Random variable less than a quantity containing random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, probability-inequalities

What is the probability of the following: $P\left(Z_j>\frac{\epsilon}{a_j*R}\left(\sum^{M}_{m=j+1} ~ a_m*R*X_m+1\right)\right)$

where $Z_j$ and $X_m$ are independent and identically distributed random variables, where they are continuous random variables that take values from 0 to infinity. having the following CDF:

$F_{Z}(z){=}\frac{\gamma\left(B,\frac{\sqrt{z}}
{u}\right)}{\Gamma(B)}$

$F_{X_m}(x){=}\frac{\gamma\left(B,\frac{\sqrt{x}}
{u}\right)}{\Gamma(B)}$

$a_m$, $\epsilon$, $u$, and $R$ are constants.

The summation of all $a_m$ is: $\sum^{M}_{m=1}a_m=1$
where $M=6$.

Comment: Please don't repost a question when it's closed: just edit it.  In this instance, continuing my comment to your now deleted first version, the difference of random variables appears to be a linear combination of Gamma variates (if I guess correctly about your notation).  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479 for a general method of computing its distributional properties.

Comment: so the first step I should move the right hand side to the left hand side like this $P\left(Z_j-\frac{\epsilon}{a_j*R}\sum^{M}_{m=j+1} ~ a_m*R*X_m>1\right)$

Comment: The idea is right but the algebra is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I mean this $P\left(Z_j-\frac{\epsilon}{a_j*R}\sum^{M}_{m=j+1} ~ a_m*R*X_m>\frac{\epsilon}{a_j*R}\right)$

Comment: That looks better ;-).